# Import (partial) matrix resulting from sliding window analysis

Tags: r

I presently have a table with three columns describing a position in a matrix and a value of statistical association (specifically allelic association), so:

x y z
1 2 0.1
1 3 0.2
2 3 0.4
2 4 0.1
3 4 0.2
...

The matrix lacks diagonal values (there was no value calculated for, say, position (1,1), (2,2), or (3,3). Additionally, because the values were calculated only in windows smaller than the entire extent of possible x and y positions, the resultant matrix is incomplete.

What I would like to do is import this table into R and then convert it into a matrix which can then be summarized with an approach such as a heatmap. Given the sliding window nature of the matrix standard vector to matrix transformations don't seem like an option. Any advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pls explain better what is your problem,I really did not understand, is it just you have some missing values?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I think it is true that calculations falling outside of the window would be considered missing. At present these missing values are not part of the larger table, though being able to input these might be a solution. The reason that a sliding window approach was applied as opposed to calculating the relationship between all positions was computational (too many positions) but also we're only interested in a subset of the larger matrix of relationship. Specifically we want to see how this relationship changes in particular focal sections of the matrix.